# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to implement CountVectorizer on a tags data but everytime it throws attribute error , tried everything and still cant understand why this error. This is my code,

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer = lambda x: x.split(" "))

tag_dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(tag_data['Tags'])
```

and this is the error i get:

```
`AttributeError                            
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-7a05ab3b6655> in <module>()

      7 # and learns the vocabulary; second, it transforms our training data
      8 # into feature vectors. The input to fit_transform should be a list of strings.                  
 ----> 9 tag_dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(tag_data['Tags'])


3 frames


/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in _preprocess(doc, accent_function, lower)
     
     66     """
      
     67     if lower:

     ---> 68         doc = doc.lower()
     
     69     if accent_function is not None:

     70         doc = accent_function(doc)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'`
```

Answer (score 5):

You can complete the code by the following syntax and eliminate if any value is taking null by list comprehension.

```
tag_dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform([str(val) for val in tag_data['Tags'] if val is not np.nan])
```

Do let me know if this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

'doc' is not containing any data/string in it, it is None type . None is not the meaning of none or blank , its a type.
check that with a condition like "if doc is None:" it will be true there.

Comment: and since it is None type, it wont/doesn't have attribute 'lower' and many other attributes.

Comment: in other words, try this --
```python
doc1 = None  
doc2 = "STRING"  
```
print(doc2.lower()) <--- will work.   
print(doc1.lower()) <--- wont work, attribute error ---because doc1 is not string type, it is None type.

Answer (score 0):

Try and convert it to a string as lower is a string function and since one of the data passed into the CountVectorizer is a NoneType, It literally hooks there